# Please use proper en-dashes for ranges in SO Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

Tagged [spelling](/questions/tagged/spelling) since some wonderful person is probably watching it for these quick fixes and it's in the same spirit as a simple typo.

Please replace the hyphens on the careers profile page with en-dashes, Unicode code point U+2013.  Hyphens are for hyphenated words *only*.  Reference: [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)

Bad:
[image: scrshot]

Better:

> ## Computer Science, …
>
> #### *2010 – 2014* (regular space)
>
> #### *2010 – 2014* (with U+202F narrow no-break space)
>
> #### *2010–2014* (no space)

Comment: Hmm.  Not a Grammar-Nazi situation - would this be considered a Unicode-Nazi, or Punctuation-Nazi problem?

Comment: @AdamDavis [As your grandmother would attest](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zytdn.jpg), punctuation is important :) For the record, accepted style when limited to ASCII is to use two/three hyphens for an en-/em-dash: I bought 20--30 apples at the market---they were delicious.

Comment: I didn't think there was supposed to be a space between the number and the en dash?

Comment: @grgarside I've always seen it as more-or-less optional. You really don't want *too* much space between, but some fonts will awkwardly clash the dash with other characters. Personally, I like to use a half-space (also called thin space). I make the call on a font-by-font basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good eye, thanks for pointing this out! A fix is on its way.